# How can I add 5 numbers on a empty array using 1 textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, max, user-input

I want to enter five numbers into the array using one text box. And find the max number print it when I click the result button. I want to enter a number one by one when I clicked the add button it automatically add one by one to the array. HTML with JavaScript

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    
    function Add(numbers) {
      numbers = [];
      for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
       var numbers = input[x];
      }
    return numbers;
    }
    
    function findMax(arr) {
      var max = arr[0];
      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        if(arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
      }
     return max;
    }
    
    function Result() {
      document.write(document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = findMax(arr))
    
    }
```

```html
 <p id = "demo">Print here the result</p>
 <input type = "text"; id = "input">
 <button onclick = "Add()">Add</button>
 <button onclick = "Result()">Result</button>
```

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: Please improve your question, remove the bold and explain what is not working. also, please construct your code in a snippet.

Comment: I can't input a number into array using one textbox

Comment: @LizQuenUpdate you can, if you think a bit about it.

Comment: I will for sure. By the way I am new to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there are many errors, that needs to be fixed, in the code you wrote:

- You are declaring the `numbers`array twice, inside your `add` function, while you should be declaring it only once globally outside of it.
- You don't need a loop to add the `input` value into the `array`, just use `.push()`.
- You don't need to return the `numbers` array after adding an element.
- Don't use `document.write()` to show the result, just use `document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = findMax(numbers)`.
- Make sure to pass the right `numbers` array to your `findMax()`function, instead of `arr` in `findMax(arr)`.

**Demo:**

This is a demo with these errors corrected.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var numbers = [];

function Add() {
  if (numbers.length < 5) {
    numbers.push(+input.value);
    input.value = "";
  }
}

function findMax(arr) {
  var max = arr[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > max)
      max = arr[i];
  }
  return max;
}

function Result() {
  console.log(numbers);
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = findMax(numbers);

}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Print here the result</p>
<input type="text" ; id="input">
<button onclick="Add()">Add</button>
<button onclick="Result()">Result</button>
```

Comment: How can I maximize it into 5 input? Do I need to put an if else statement ? Sorry for my grammar. This is not my language.

Comment: @LizQuenUpdate Yes, you can use a simple if statement. I made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the 5 elements in an array using a single textbox, if they are seperated by single space do this:

```js
var arr = input.split(' ');
```

This will create an array 'arr' with the numbers in it!

Comment: Good idea! But what I need is put it one by one.

Comment: Do you mean with no spaces or do you mean like input a number press 'enter' and then input another number?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code bellow :

```
<body>
  <p id = "demo">Print here the result</p>
  <input type = "text"; id = "input">
  <button onclick = "Add()">Add</button>
  <button onclick = "Result()">Result</button>
<script>



var numbers=[];
function Add() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  if(input != ""){
 numbers.push(parseFloat(input));
  }
 document.getElementById('input').value="";
 console.log(numbers);
}



function Result() {
    console.log(numbers);
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Math.max.apply(null, numbers);;

}

</script>
</body>
```